# Postman only showing error message and no request is working

Tags: node.js, express, postman

Hi so I'm new in this domain and I'm working on some big project so here's the issue, i'm trying to run postman changing the requests from get to post etc but it's not working here's the app.js file

```
const express = require('express')
 const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const con= require("./helpers/connection");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// parse env variables


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.con = con
   next()
  })


app.use("/", require("./routes/routes"));

  // Handling errors

  //* Handling not mapped routes

 app.use((req, res, next) => {
 const error = new Error("Not found");
 error.status = 404;
 next(error);
 });

 //* Handling thrown or server errors
 app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
    message: error.message,
     },
    });
  });


    app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
    })
```

And this is my router file

```
const express = require("express")
  const router = express.Router()
const userController = require("../../controllers/usersController.js")

router.get("/", userController.getUsers)
router.get("/:id", userController.getUserById)
router.post("/create", userController.create)
router.put("/:id", userController.edit)
router.delete("/:id", userController.delete)

module.exports = router
```

when i go to postman and try any of these request this is what i get

```
{
     "error": {
            "message": "Not found"
             }
}
```

Please if anyone has any idea why it's not working do share with me

Comment: Add `console.log(req.method, req.url)` bellow `req.con = con` just before `next()` to see the urls and method. Then if you try in postman `http://localhost:port/` and you see in console `GET /` and you still get 404 try to change `app.use("/", require("./routes/routes"));` to `app.use("/users", require("./routes/routes"));` and in postman try `http://localhost:port/users` Maybe it just does not support single `/`

Comment: okay so i do get the /GEt in console and the 404 ,but also when i use /users i'll get the same error with Get /users in console..why exactly did ou choose users please?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works just fine. There must be something else wrong. Is the path right here `require("./routes/routes")`? Can you verify the router file is being required,? Just add `console.log('Hello from', __filename);` to the router file.

Comment: can u tell me what exactly happens when u run postman? what should be showed ? because i don't know where the problem is..i  need your help please

Comment: @Molda i find the issue i have to put the right path localhost:3000/api/users but here i have a problem do you hava any knowledge about passport so you could help me out please?